# Derby.js - npm install derby successful, but derby command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, derbyjs

I'm following the [Derby.js getting started guide](http://derbyjs.com/#getting_started). I have run

```
$ npm install -g derby
```

and everything succeeds, but when I enter

```
$ derby new app-name
```

I get:

```
-bash: derby: command not found
```

I'm on Mac OS 10.8, Node v0.10.3, npm v1.2.17

Comment: Had the same problem with the alpha version (0.6).
Works fine if I install 0.5.16

Answer (score 1):

Check if NODE_PATH and PATH variables contain the location to executable files

> export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node"
>
> export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH"

See this [page](http://shapeshed.com/setting-up-nodejs-and-npm-on-mac-osx/).

Answer (score 1):

The command line interface portion of Derby is vaporware so far. There is no `bin` setting in the `package.json`, which is what instructs `npm` to make executable scripts.

I suspect the documentation got ahead of the source code.

Answer (score 1):

As of June 2014, the docs are still for Derby 0.5 while 0.6 is in npm. Apparently, [generator-derby](https://github.com/derbyparty/generator-derby) is currently the recommended way to start a 0.6 project:

```
npm install -g yo
npm install -g generator-derby
mkdir myapp
cd myapp
yo derby
```

Make sure to install and start MongoDB and then `npm start`.